# Add totals to the groups

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, grouping

I am recently new working with Crystal Report and  I am a bit confused how I can implement my sum on the groups.
I group my tasks with taskID:

```
20422   416.46   Project01
20422   788.73   Project03
20422   361.85   Project04
20422   4,414.37 Project01  
20423   806.26   Project08
20423   6787.67  Project09
```

How can I add the subtotals for each of my group and where do I place it because I've already had them in the group footer, so it will look like:

```
20422   416.46   Project01
20422   788.73   Project03
20422   361.85   Project04
20422   4,414.37 Project01  
        45708.41

20423   806.26   Project08
20423   6787.67  Project09
        7593.93
```

Comment: if you need totals then you need to take the summary higher than the existing group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to group by project# as well? Group footer or header doesn't matter, you will get the same number

I'm thinking you want to group like this:

```
Group 1 Project [In In Group Header sum your data] 
    Group 2 task   [In Group footer sum your data]
```